# What is the recursion step being used for the saturation of mutual information in the area law?

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

I am trying to understand Lemma 16 of this paper, ["Exponential Decay of Correlations Implies Area Law"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2947), and I'm getting stuck on the recursion step. The essential bit is going from Equation (B9) to Equation (B10). I don't see how we can keep on doing recursion to smaller and smaller regions until we get to the size $l_0$.

Here's the lemma:

> Let $\rho_1,...,n \in D(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$ and $s \in [n]$ be a particular site. Then for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $l_0 \gt 0 $ there is a $l$ satisfying $1 \le l / l_0 \le \exp(\mathcal{O}(1/\epsilon))$ and a connected region $X_{2l} \equiv X_{L,l/2} X_{C,l} X_{R,l/2}$ of $2l$ sites (the borders $X_{L,l/2}$ and $X_{R,l/2}$ with $l/2$ sites each, and the central region $X_{C,l}$ with $l$ sites) centred at most $l_0 \exp(\mathcal{O}(1/\epsilon))$ sites away from $s$ (see Fig. 4) such that: $I(X_{C,l}: X_{L,l/2} X_{R,l/2}) \le \epsilon l$.

They show a result: $H(X_{2l}) \le 4H(X_{l/2}) - \epsilon l$, where $H$ is the Shannon entropy ($I$ is the mutual information). They then do recursion to get:

$$H(X_{2l}) \le l - \log_4(l/l_0) \epsilon l.$$

How did they get to this last step? I would like to see the recursion done a bit more explicitly.